# Error con funciones WHERE, AND y GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

estoy tratando de hacer este programa, y todo funciona bien hasta que meto la condicion "and SUM(p.total) > 150", no se porque ocurre esto, si alguien pudiera ayudarme le estaría muy agradecido.

```
select
    c.nombre,
    c.apellidos,
    p.id_cliente,
    SUM(p.total)
from
    pago p
    inner join cliente c on c.id_cliente = p.id_cliente
where p.fecha_pago like '2005%' and SUM(p.total) > 150
Group by
    p.id_cliente
order by
    SUM(p.total);
```

Comment: No adjuntas detalles de tus tablas, por lo que será más dificil ayudarte, de cualquier manera prueba algo como `... where p.fecha_pago like '2005%' Group by p.id_cliente HAVING SUM(p.total) > 150  order by SUM(p.total);`

Comment: Acabo de probar tu sugerencia, y a funcionado! Usar "Having" en vez de "and" ha hecho que funcione el codigo, muchas gracias! :3    Tratare de ajuntar detalles de las tablas la proxima vez, no pense que fuera necesario xD Edit: como marco que la pregunta fue solucionada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar la función de agregación `SUM` sobre cada cliente, primero debes **agrupar por cliente**, para luego filtrar el total de pagos por cliente mayor a 150 con un `HAVING`. Tu consulta quedaría:

```
select
    c.nombre,
    c.apellidos,
    p.id_cliente,
    SUM(p.total)
from
    pago p
    inner join cliente c on c.id_cliente = p.id_cliente
where p.fecha_pago like '2005%' 
Group by
    p.id_cliente
having
    SUM(p.total) > 150
order by
    SUM(p.total);
```